# How to view "last updated" date in the Microsoft Windows App Store?

Tags: microsoft-store

In the Microsoft Store how do you view the date an app was last updated, it only lists the date the app was first published.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an updated method for a 2022

Instructions are the same. Let me quote them.

"In the URL you'll notice the "Product ID" in the case of Skype it's 9wzdncrfj364. Replace the term "PRODUCTIDHERE" in the URL below with this "Product ID" and paste it in your browser:"

https://storeedgefd.dsx.mp.microsoft.com/v9.0/pages/pdp?productId=PRODUCTIDHERE&market=US&locale=en-US&appVersion=22205.1401.0.0&deviceFamily=Windows.Desktop

"Search the returned JSON file for the word "LastUpdateDateUtc", directly after this it will list the date the app was last updated."

Comment: Some apps don't seem to have a "LastUpdateDateUtc" field. For example, iCloud: 9PKTQ5699M62

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft store doesn't show the date an app was last updated however it is available via their API. I'm sure someone could write a quick tool to query this but here's the manual process.

Instead of using the Microsoft Store on your computer search for the app via the [Microsoft Stores website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/store/apps/windows). Find the app your looking for, for example [skype](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/skype/9wzdncrfj364).

In the URL you'll notice the "Product ID" in the case of Skype it's `9wzdncrfj364`. Replace the term "PRODUCTIDHERE" in the URL below with this "Product ID" and paste it in your browser:

https://storeedgefd.dsx.mp.microsoft.com/v8.0/pages/pdp?productId=PRODUCTIDHERE&market=US&locale=en-US&appversion=11703.1001.45.0

For example:

https://storeedgefd.dsx.mp.microsoft.com/v8.0/pages/pdp?productId=9wzdncrfj364&market=US&locale=en-US&appversion=11703.1001.45.0

Search the [returned JSON file](https://storeedgefd.dsx.mp.microsoft.com/v8.0/pages/pdp?productId=9wzdncrfj364&market=US&locale=en-US&appversion=11703.1001.45.0) for the word "LastUpdateDateUtc", directly after this it will list the date the app was last updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got an error message of "Required parameter deviceFamily was not specified." and fixed it by adding `&deviceFamily=Windows.Universal` to the URL